# JWT token has been not Loaded In my header || request

Tags: express, jwt, middleware

I am a student and trying to integrate a login and sign-up module which use JWT token authorization, also i am using express server to handling the requests,

I am facing problem in getting fatch my token which i assing to user at the time of login or register, my middleware function can't able to find jwt token in req.body || req.query || req.headers["x-access-token"]; it shows "**ReferenceError: token is not defined**"
please help me to point out the problem

I am using normal HTML form to Post the request.

```
// Here is my all code



require("dotenv").config();
require('./public/config/auth_Database').connect();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const PORT = 3000 || process.env.PORT;
const { models } = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const User = require('./public/models/user');
const req = require("express/lib/request");

// Server Side code

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    //register logic
    try { 
    
        const  Username = req.body.Username;
        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;
       
        //if any feild is empty
        if (!(Username && email && password)) {
            res.status(400).send("All feild is required!");
        }

        //check if user is already exists 
        const oldUser = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (oldUser) {
            return res.status(409).send("User is already exist | please try to login");
        }
        // Password encryption
        encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

        //create user in database
        const user = await User.create({
            Username,
            email: email.toLowerCase(),
            password: encryptedPassword,
        });

        //create token 
        const token = jwt.sign(
            { user_id: user._id, email },
            process.env.TOKEN_KEY,
            { expiresIn: "2h" }
        );
        // save user token
        user.token = token;
        user.save();
        // return new user
        res.status(201).redirect('/home');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`your error is: ${error}`);
    }
})

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        //accepting perameters form request
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        //cheking if all entered
        if (!(email && password)) {
            res.status(400).send("Please Enter All required details");
        }

        //now valid the user
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
            //create token
            const token = jwt.sign(
                { user_id: user._id, email },
                process.env.TOKEN_KEY,
                {
                    expiresIn: "2h",
                }
            );
            // asign created token to the user
            user.token = token;

            res.setHeader('user','user');
            //return the user

            res.status(200).redirect('/home');
        }
        else{
            res.status(400).send(`User Not exist || please try to register first`)
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`There is some error: ${error}`);
    }
})

app.get('/login',(req, res) => {
    res.status(200).render("Login");
})

app.get('/register',(req, res) => {
    res.status(200).render("register");
});
app.get('/home',auth,(req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).send("Index page visible");
});



// Middleware function code (auth.js).


const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = process.env;

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.body || req.query || req.headers["x-access-token"];
        if (!token) {
            return res.status(403).send("Token has been Not found try again or Relogin");
            // return res.status(403).redirect('/login');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(401).send(error);
    }
   

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.TOKEN_KEY);
        req.user = decoded;
        console.log(req.user);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(401).send(`${error}`);
    }
    return next();
};

module.exports = verifyToken;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome; for start to debug, you must look at the line number that raises the error

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should look for your token like that in your middleware

```
const authorizationHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
const token = authorizationHeader && authorizationHeader.split(' ')[1];

if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401)
```

Do not forget to send your token like that

```
Authorization: Bearer JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Postman Tip

[image: Postman Tip]